# Take Picture From Camera And Show it to the ImageView Android

Tags: android, imageview, android-camera, android-imageview, thumbnails

before i'm so sorry if my post maybe duplicated, but i have another case in this problem, i wanna show an image that i capture from camera in ImageView and after that i save it or upload it into my json file, but after i take the picture, it's stopped in `Log.i ("Error", "Maybe Here");`

no error in my code but the image cant saved into thumbnail ImageView

Here is my code, i'm using Asyntask

```
    public class StoreTodoDisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Context ctx;
    Uri imgUri;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    public static CategoryData category_data_ar[];
    public static CategoryData category_data_ar2[];
    String targetUrl;
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/DCIM/Camera/img11.jpg";
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    SharedPreferences settings;
    RestData restData;
    ImageData imgData;
    public Uri mCapturedImageURI;
    public String image_path = "";
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_display);
        targetUrl = Config.getEndPointUrl();
        ctx = this.getApplicationContext();
        System.gc();

        set_Spinner();
        set_Spinner2();

        // Toolbar show
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.actionbarCameraDisplay);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final android.support.v7.app.ActionBar abar = getSupportActionBar();
        abar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        abar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        abar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        abar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        // Back button pressed
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        if (!UserInfo.loginstatus) {
            finish();
        }
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void get_pic(View view) {
        String fileName = "temp.jpg";
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
        mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 12345);

    }

    public void save_img(View view) {
        EditText te = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.camera_display_txt);
        String msg = te.getText().toString();

        Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        int catid = (int) sp.getSelectedItemId();
        String cat = category_data_ar[catid].catid;

        Spinner sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        int catid2 = (int) sp2.getSelectedItemId();
        String cat2 = category_data_ar2[catid2].catid;

        ImageUploader uploader = new ImageUploader("display", msg, cat, cat2);
        uploader.execute(Config.getEndPointUrl() + "/uploadimage.json");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 12345) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                getimage getm = new getimage();
                getm.execute();

            }
        }
    }

    public void set_Spinner2() {
        Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        sp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        CatProductHelper helper = new CatProductHelper(ctx);
        category_data_ar2 = helper.getCategories();
        String[] isidesc = new String[category_data_ar2.length];
        for (int k = 0; k < category_data_ar2.length; k++) {
            isidesc[k] = category_data_ar2[k].catdesc;
            Log.i("AndroidRuntime", "Desc -- " + category_data_ar2[k].catdesc);
        }

        ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(
                StoreTodoDisplayActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, isidesc);
        spinnerArrayAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    }

    public void set_Spinner() {
        // set list activity
        Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        category_data_ar = StoreInfo.storeDisplayCat;
        try {

            String[] isidesc = new String[category_data_ar.length];
            Log.i("toTry", "Normal");
            for (int k = 0; k < category_data_ar.length; k++) {
                isidesc[k] = category_data_ar[k].catdesc;
                Log.i("AndroidRuntime", "Desc -- "
                        + category_data_ar[k].catdesc);
            }

            ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(
                    StoreTodoDisplayActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, isidesc);
            spinnerArrayAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            sp.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("toCatch", "NULL EXCEPTION");
            DisplayCatHelper helperDisplayCat = new DisplayCatHelper(ctx);
            CategoryData[] displayCat = helperDisplayCat.getCategories();
            String[] isidesc = new String[displayCat.length];
            for (int k = 0; k < displayCat.length; k++) {
                isidesc[k] = displayCat[k].catdesc;
                Log.i("AndroidRuntime", "Desc -- " + displayCat[k].catdesc);
            }

            ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, isidesc);
            spinnerArrayAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            sp.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        }

    }

    private class ImageUploader extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        private String url;
        private String cameraType;
        private String cameraMsg;
        private String cameraCat;
        private String catproduct;

        public ImageUploader(String type, String msg, String cat, String cat2) {
            cameraType = type;
            cameraMsg = msg;
            cameraCat = cat;
            catproduct = cat2;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(StoreTodoDisplayActivity.this, "",
                    "Uploading...", false);
            // none
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            url = params[0];
            Log.i("ncdebug", "upload image to: " + url);
            try {
                if (image_path.equals("")) {
                    Log.i("ncdebug", "bmp kosong!!!!");
                } else {
                    Log.i("ncdebug", "Ok bmp gak kosong, mari kirim");
                    restData = new RestData();
                    imgData = new ImageData();
                    restData.setTitle("Display : " + StoreInfo.storename);
                    restData.setRequestMethod(RequestMethod.POST);
                    restData.setUrl(url);
                    imgData.setImageData(url, image_path, cameraMsg, cameraCat
                                    + "-" + catproduct, UserInfo.username,
                            StoreInfo.storeid, cameraType, UserInfo.checkinid);

                    saveToDb();

                    return "Success";
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                //saveToDb();
            }
            return "Penyimpanan gagal, ulangi tahap pengambilan gambar";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String Result) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            if (Result.equals("Success")) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Data tersimpan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                // checked todo
                String vVar = StoreInfo.storeid + "-" + UserInfo.username
                        + "-displaycam";
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(vVar, true);
                editor.commit();

                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, StoreTodoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, Result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }

        }
    }

    public void saveToDb() {
        Log.i("eris", "connection failed so save to db");
        RestHelper helper = new RestHelper(ctx);
        helper.insertRest(restData);
        imgData.setRestId(helper.getRestId());
        Log.i("REST ID", helper.getRestId());
        ImageHelper imgHelper = new ImageHelper(ctx);
        imgHelper.insertRest(imgData);
    }

    public class getimage extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String orientation = "";
        Bitmap bitmap;
        BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//            Log.i("INI BACKGROUND", "LIHAT");
            try {
                String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mCapturedImageURI, projection,
                        null, null, null);
                int column_index_data = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                String capturedImageFilePath = cursor
                        .getString(column_index_data);
                String parentPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/Nestle Confect";
                String filename = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                opts.inSampleSize = 4;
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(capturedImageFilePath,
                        opts);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                File file = new File(parentPath);
                file.mkdir();
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    Log.i("absoulute path", file.getAbsolutePath());
                    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file + "/"
                            + filename, true);

                    // 5
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();
                    image_path = parentPath + "/" + filename;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    image_path = capturedImageFilePath;
                }

                byte[] thumb = null;
                try {
                    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                            capturedImageFilePath);
                    orientation = exif
                            .getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
                    thumb = exif.getThumbnail();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }

                if (thumb != null) {
                    Log.i("IMAGEVIEW", "THUMBNAIL");
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(thumb, 0,
                            thumb.length);
                } else {
                    Log.i("IMAGEVIEW", "REALFILE");
                    return "not fine";
                }
                return "fine";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "not fine";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // PROBLEM HERE
            Log.i("ERROR", "HERE MAYBE");
            if (result.equals("fine")) {
                ImageView gambarHasil = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camera_display_img);
                gambarHasil.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                if (!orientation.equals("1")) {
                    Log.i("ORIENTATION", orientation);
                    float angel = 0f;
                    if (orientation.equals("6")) {
                        angel = 90f;
                    } else if (orientation.equals("8")) {
                        angel = -90f;
                    }
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    gambarHasil.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX); // required
                    matrix.postRotate((float) angel, gambarHasil.getDrawable()
                            .getBounds().width() / 2, gambarHasil.getDrawable()
                            .getBounds().height() / 2);
                    gambarHasil.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        ctx,
                        "Error, Try To Take Picture Again",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your activity just got restarted you need to put below code in manifest where you declare. and save your uri on saveInstanceState and restore it on onrestoreinstancestate. it will be resolve your issue

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this lib,Provides support above API 14
https://github.com/google/cameraview